# Error importing custom css and js in Angular 5

Tags: css, angular, angular5

I'm really struggling on how to import my custom css and js to my Angular5 project.

I'm new on Angular so and explanation of what I'm doing wrong will be awesome.

I want to import the css styles globally in the project.

The structure of the project is:

```
 -representacioApp
 --representacio-app
 ---src
 ----assets
 -----css
 ------style.css
 -----vendors
 ------css
 -------vendor.bundle.base.css
 -------vendor.bundle.addons.css
 ------iconfonts
       ...
 ---.angular-cli.json
```

And the code

My `.angular-cli.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "representacio-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "prt",
      "styles": [
        "assets/css/style.css",
        "assets/vendors/iconfonts/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
        "assets/vendors/iconfonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "assets/vendors/css/vendor.bundle.base.css",
        "assets/vendors/css/vendor.bundle.addons.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "assets/vendors/js/vendor.bundle.base.js",
        "assets/vendors/js/vendor.bundle.addons.js",
        "assets/js/off-canvas.js",
        "assets/js/hoverable-collapse.js",
        "assets/js/misc.js",
        "assets/js/settings.js",
        "assets/js/todolist.js",
        "assets/js/dashboard.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "devCa": "environments/environment.dev.ca.ts",
        "devEs": "environments/environment.dev.es.ts",
        "devCaMock": "environments/environment.dev.ca.mock.ts",
        "devEsMock": "environments/environment.dev.es.mock.ts",
        "prodCa": "environments/environment.prod.ca.ts",
        "prodEs": "environments/environment.prod.es.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

The routes of the files are correctly written so the problem isnt here, I tried to read the error, but as I said I'm pretty new on angular and not used to this kind of errores.

There are a lot of errors that maybe are in the css or where?

CODE OF THE ERROR: https://justpaste.it/6iq4p

Comment: For angular 5, try placing ../ before the file paths.

Comment: In all the filepaths? @3Demon

Comment: Do your included css files have links to things like images in them? If so those images need to be in the exact path mentioned in those files.

Comment: Okey I fixed most of the errors, now I'm getting a couple that I cant fix: https://justpaste.it/53n9y @Mathias

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

`src/assets/css/style.css`

Comment: When I tried in the error appears in the console Error ... in src/src/assets/css/style.css

Comment: Sorry I didn't focus to `root: "src"`, Can you show your css file?

Comment: Okey I fixed most of the errors, now I'm getting a couple that I cant fix: justpaste.it/53n9y @Saidabbos

Answer (score 0):

For All Files Try Like This

```
 ./src/assets/css/style.css
```

Hope It Will Work